# How to count weekly unique accesses in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have this query in MySQL to check the unique accesses to a system:

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id_user) AS total, access_day FROM access
WHERE (access_day BETWEEN '2018-01-21' AND '2019-01-21')
GROUP BY access_day`

It works!

The client asked to check the weekly unique accesses to his system, if the user accesses at least 1 once during the period of 1 week, would already tell him access, how to do? I tried this way, but the numbers are wrong:

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id_user) AS total, access_day FROM access
WHERE (access_day BETWEEN '2018-01-21' AND '2019-01-21')
GROUP BY WEEK(access_day)`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

Example:

```
SELECT FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(sales_time) -MOD(TO_DAYS(sales_time) -1, 7)) AS week_beginning,
       SUM(gross) AS total,
       COUNT(*) AS transactions
FROM sales
GROUP BY FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(sales_time) -MOD(TO_DAYS(sales_time) -1, 7))
ORDER BY FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(sales_time) -MOD(TO_DAYS(sales_time) -1, 7))
```

And, if your business rules say your weeks start on Mondays, change the -1 to -2.